#!ERROR [LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 132
I'm new to LDAP. I'm using Apache directory studio. I create a server and a new connection to use it for authentication of my device. Then, i added my ldif file and execute it using the connection created . But i keep on getting this error:
#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2024-04-23T13:17:38.525
#!ERROR  [LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 129     Add Request : Entry     dn: dc=iberdrola,dc=es     objectclass: domain     objectclass: top     structuralobjectclass: domain     dc: iberdrola : ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=iberdrola,dc=es
dn: dc=iberdrola,dc=es
changetype: add
structuralobjectclass: domain
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: iberdrola

#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2024-04-23T13:17:38.525
#!ERROR  [LDAP result code 32 - noSuchObject] NO_SUCH_OBJECT: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 130     Add Request : Entry     dn: ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es     objectclass: top     objectclass: organizationalUnit     ou: usuarios     description: Container for user entries     structuralobjectclass: organizationalUnit : ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
dn: ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
changetype: add
ou: usuarios
description: Container for user entries
structuralobjectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit

#!RESULT ERROR
#!CONNECTION ldap://localhost:10389
#!DATE 2024-04-23T13:17:38.525
#!ERROR  [LDAP result code 16 - noSuchAttribute] NO_SUCH_ATTRIBUTE: failed for MessageType : ADD_REQUEST Message ID : 131     Add Request : Entry     dn: uid=U000000,ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es     objectclass: top     objectclass: organizationalRole     objectclass: usuarioIberdrola     objectclass: equiposCTstar     perfil-usu: ADMINISTRACION     perfil-usu: VISUALIZACION     perfil-cat4: ALL     perfil-cat4: INTEGRATOR     perfil-cat4: OTHER     perfil-cat3: ALL     perfil-cat3: EXPLOTACION     perfil-cat3: PST_SERVICIO     perfil-cat2: ALL     perfil-cat2: MANUFACTURER     perfil-cat2: OTHER     perfil-cat1: ALL     perfil-cat1: NORTE     perfil-cat1: NOROESTE     perfil-cat1: MADRID     perfil-cat1: CENTRO     perfil-cat1: ESTE_NORTE     perfil-cat1: ESTE_SUR     cn: Apellido1 Apellido2 Nombre     structuralobjectclass: organizationalRole     userpassword: 0x55 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x30      uid: U000000     perfil-cat8: ALL     perfil-cat8: TG     perfil-cat8: SPVMT     perfil-cat7: ALL     perfil-cat7: CT_IN     perfil-cat7: CT_EXT     perfil-cat6: ALL     perfil-cat6: STAR     perfil-cat6: PRICE     perfil-cat5: ALL     perfil-cat5: REMOTA     perfil-cat5: CARGADOR     perfil-cat5: CONCENTRADOR : ERR_13735_ELEMENT_FOR_OID_DOES_NOT_EXIST ATTRIBUTE_TYPE for OID perfil-usu does not exist!
dn: uid=U000000,ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
changetype: add
perfil-usu: ADMINISTRACION
perfil-usu: VISUALIZACION
perfil-cat4: ALL
perfil-cat4: INTEGRATOR
perfil-cat4: OTHER
perfil-cat3: ALL
perfil-cat3: EXPLOTACION
perfil-cat3: PST_SERVICIO
perfil-cat2: ALL
perfil-cat2: MANUFACTURER
perfil-cat2: OTHER
perfil-cat1: ALL
perfil-cat1: NORTE
perfil-cat1: NOROESTE
perfil-cat1: MADRID
perfil-cat1: CENTRO
perfil-cat1: ESTE_NORTE
perfil-cat1: ESTE_SUR
cn: Apellido1 Apellido2 Nombre
structuralobjectclass: organizationalRole
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalRole
objectclass: usuarioIberdrola
objectclass: equiposCTstar
userpassword:: VTAwMDAwMA==
uid: U000000
perfil-cat8: ALL
perfil-cat8: TG
perfil-cat8: SPVMT
perfil-cat7: ALL
perfil-cat7: CT_IN
perfil-cat7: CT_EXT
perfil-cat6: ALL
perfil-cat6: STAR
perfil-cat6: PRICE
perfil-cat5: ALL
perfil-cat5: REMOTA
perfil-cat5: CARGADOR
perfil-cat5: CONCENTRADOR


This is the content of the ldif that i would like to execute it:
dn: dc=iberdrola,dc=es
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
dc: iberdrola
structuralobjectclass: domain

dn: ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: usuarios
description: Container for user entries
structuralobjectclass: organizationalUnit

dn: uid=U000000,ou=usuarios,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalRole
objectclass: usuarioIberdrola
objectclass: equiposCTstar
uid: U000000
cn: Apellido1 Apellido2 Nombre
structuralobjectclass: organizationalRole
perfil-usu: ADMINISTRACION
perfil-usu: VISUALIZACION
perfil-cat1: ALL
perfil-cat1: NORTE
perfil-cat1: NOROESTE
perfil-cat1: MADRID
perfil-cat1: CENTRO
perfil-cat1: ESTE_NORTE
perfil-cat1: ESTE_SUR
perfil-cat2: ALL
perfil-cat2: MANUFACTURER
perfil-cat2: OTHER
perfil-cat3: ALL
perfil-cat3: EXPLOTACION
perfil-cat3: PST_SERVICIO
perfil-cat4: ALL
perfil-cat4: INTEGRATOR
perfil-cat4: OTHER
perfil-cat5: ALL
perfil-cat5: REMOTA
perfil-cat5: CARGADOR
perfil-cat5: CONCENTRADOR
perfil-cat6: ALL
perfil-cat6: STAR
perfil-cat6: PRICE
perfil-cat7: ALL
perfil-cat7: CT_IN
perfil-cat7: CT_EXT
perfil-cat8: ALL
perfil-cat8: TG
perfil-cat8: SPVMT
userpassword: U000000

dn: ou=grupos,dc=iberdrola,dc=es
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: grupos
description: Container for user entries
structuralobjectclass: organizationalUnit



Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
